# How to get kernel index for grub default?

Tags: grub2

**Scenario**

I can see the list of kernels I have by either holding `shift` on `boot` or by `$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

I know that I can change the default boot kernel in `/etc/default/grub` by setting `GRUB_DEFAULT=N` where N is the id for the kernel. Where I'm stuck is getting the corresponding id's for the kernels.

**Question**

How can I tell which kernel corresponds to an id of 0 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /etc/default/grub:

---

## GRUB_DEFAULT=

The default menu entry. This may be a number, in which case it identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero, or the title of a menu entry, or the special string ‘saved’. Using the title may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default even though there may be a variable number of entries before it.

For example, if you have (grep -i menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg):

```
menuentry 'Example GNU/Linux distribution' --class gnu-linux { ... }
```

then you can make this the default using:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Example GNU/Linux distribution'
```

**If you set this to ‘saved’**, then the default menu entry will be that saved by ‘**GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT**’, grub-set-default, or grub-reboot.

The default is ‘0’.

---

## GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=

**If this option is set to ‘true’**, then, when an entry is selected, it saves it as a new default entry for use by future runs of GRUB. This is only useful if ‘**GRUB_DEFAULT=saved**’; it is a separate option because ‘GRUB_DEFAULT=saved’ is useful without this option, in conjunction with grub-set-default or grub-reboot. Unset by default.

---